# Received Threshold via Query

Tags: query

I'm trying to write a query to pull customers who have not engaged with emails. One of my requirements is that the customers should have received at least 30 emails over the past year. How do I do this via a sql query? For example, when running a report, there's an option to set the "Received Threshold". I want a similar functionality, but with a query.

Comment: Is "Received Threshold" a custom field on your contact object? What are you using to record these emails: Tasks, Campaigns, some Marketing Automation tool?

Comment: Received Threshold is not a custom field for me. If I go to "Report" under the Interactions tab, then if I try to create a report, and in the drop-down I select Subscriber Reports | Unengaged Subscribers for a list, it then opens up an option down below for Received Threshold, which is the minimum number of emails the customer should have received for the report to pull him/her. I want something similar, but through a query where I can pull customers based on a minimum number of emails they've received within the past year.

Comment: Are you using Exacttarget or some other marketing automation tool?

Comment: I am using ExactTarget.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `HAVING` clause.

For a `HAVING` clause, you typically group by a lookup or master id and query on the child object. For example, you could query contacts and group by AccountId. 
From there you could add a `Count()` clause on one of your grouped fields.

Something like this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(Name)
FROM Email
GROUP BY CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 30
```

When I tried to add a `GROUP BY` on a datetime field (to filter for the last year), The system did not allow me to use CreateDate or LastModifieDateTime.

I think the solution is to add calc field that calculates the current year and use that as a `GROUP BY` field. ie:

```
SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(Name)
FROM Email
GROUP BY Created_Year_Calc__c, CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 30 AND Created_Year_Calc__c > LAST_N_YEARS:1
```

I *think* this will work - I got the query to work, but you'll have to verify if it's returning correct data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you're explaining. Here is what I am currently using in my query:

SELECT distinct subscriberkey FROM _Sent WHERE EventDate > dateadd(day,-360,getdate()) AND ListID=2236 AND SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberID FROM _Open WHERE EventDate > dateadd(day,-360,getdate())) AND SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberID FROM _Click WHERE EventDate > dateadd(day,-360,getdate()))

This pulls emails from a list who have received at least one email within the last year and have not opened or clicked within that year. How would I fit your suggestion into this?

Comment: This looks like SQL not SOQL. Where are you running this query?

Comment: Within exacttarget... Under interactions -> Query

Comment: I'm sorry - thought you were directly running this query in Salesforce - it looks like there are some differences in query syntax (and functionality) that will cause you some problems here. If you are running this in Apex code, then you should be fine, however...